# How to check IS NULL in dynamic query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, dynamic-sql, isnull

I did following store procedure using dynamic query, see the following blueprint of code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Report] (
 @LocationId INT = NULL
,@UserId INT = NULL)
```

DECLARE @miscquery NVARCHAR (MAX);
begin
SET @miscquery='

```
                       SELECT 
                        ,A.AgreementNumber AS Contract
                        ,A.AgreementId
                        
                    FROM tblAgreement A
                    
                    WHERE 
                    AND (A.IsDeleted = 0 or A.IsDeleted is null)
                    AND (
                                (
                                    ' + convert(NVARCHAR(30), @LocationId) + ' IS NULL  
                                    AND (
                                    A.CheckoutLocation IN (
                                        SELECT LocationId
                                        FROM [dbo].[tblUserLocations]
                                        WHERE UserID = ' + convert(VARCHAR(10), @userId) +' 
                                            AND IsDeleted = 0
                                        )
                                    OR A.CheckoutLocation IS NULL
                                    )
                                )
                                OR A.CheckoutLocation =   ' + convert(VARCHAR(10), @LocationId) +' 
                        )'
    
                    
    
                EXEC (@miscquery)
end
)
```

here when i execute the query with @Locationid is null, results doesn't return table, it returns like following

(63 rows affected)

(2325 rows affected)

please help me. thank you

Comment: Use a parameterized query instead of building a SQL statement with concatenation. That  will address the NULL issue and provide other benefits.

Comment: Where are the variables `@userId` and `@LocationId` coming from? They aren't parameters, nor are they declared. And @DanGuzman is right, this doesn't even need to be a dynamic statement (let alone an **parametrised** one). Use a parametrise statement and handle your `NULL` values. If this is a catch-all query, then it'll very likely be worth adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query as well so as bad plans aren't cached for different runs.

Comment: Hi, how to write paramerterize query to check is null, can you give sample code, and i edited the code, please look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have there cannot be your actual code, firstly because right at the start you try to set a variable called `@miscquery` before you declare it. There's also no reason for this code to be dynamic, so it's clear you're doing some other stuff as well.

I will take it as a given that for some reason you "need" dynamic SQL. I will put in the standard warning about sanitising your inputs. That was it.

OK. Even if `@miscquery` had been declared, the code as written will not produce any results. It will either throw a syntax error, or do nothing, depending on your setting for [`concat_null_yields_null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Let's take the likely case: you have the default setting for this, which means that when you concatenate a varchar to `null`, the result is `null`.

Observe the following code:

```
declare @locationId int = null;
select 'this sentence ends with...' + convert(nvarchar(30), @locationId);
```

What will be the output?

1. "This sentence ends with... null"
2. "This sentence ends with..."
3. `null`

The answer is 3. And notice: that's not a string with the value "null". That's just `null`. When you `convert` the `null` value to a string, you don't get a string with the value "null", you get the `null` value.

OK, so now we try to add `null` to the end of our string. When you try to concatenate the `null` value to a string with the `+` operator, the entire result is `null`.

Therefore, your entire `@miscquery` variable is `null` at the end of the assignment.

So what you are then doing is the same as this:

```
declare @myquery varchar(max) = null;
exec sp_executesql @myquery
```

Which is valid, and doesn't throw any error, but does nothing. Then the rest of your code does whatever it does, and produces the results you see.

if `concat_null_yields_null` was set to off then you would get a syntax error, because the resulting text would not be valid SQL when you handed it to `sp_executesql`.

As Dan said, the best and safest solution would be to parameterize your inputs. But putting that aside, the solution you need would look something like the following. In the `iif()` function, I look at the value of `@locationId`. If it is `null`, then I want the string "null". If it is not `null`, then I want the string conversion of whatever value it has.

```
declare @locationId int = null;

declare @query varchar(max) = 
   'select * from mytable where ' 
    + iif(@locationId is null, 'null', convert(nvarchar(30), @locationId)) 
    + ' is null';

print @query;
```

Comment: Hi i tried above iif condition, but getting same output

Comment: You've probably put it inside the dynamic sql instead of using it to construct the dynamic sql. Please edit your answer to include your *actual* procedure code (the code you currently have is still syntactically invalid and so can't be your real code), and I will update my answer with the exact code you need.